# How many drives do I have?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, centos, raid

This is the first time I ordered a dedicated server with 3 HDDs and I am quite confused. My limited knowledge tells me that

- `/dev/sda`
- `/dev/sdb`
- `/dev/sdc`

are the 3 drives that I actually have.

But, using the command `fdisk -l | grep '^Disk'` gives the following output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5413d59f
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x541faf6a
Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x54145359
Disk /dev/md2: 995.2 GB, 995237888000 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/md1: 4291 MB, 4291756032 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/mapper/sys1AP7-root: 990.9 GB, 990929485824 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/md0: 536 MB, 536805376 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/mapper/sys1AP7-vartmp: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Disk /dev/mapper/sys1AP7-tmp:
```

it appears I have more than 3 drives.

What exactly are the following?

- `/dev/md2`
- `/dev/md1`
- `/dev/mapper/sys1AP7-root`
- `/dev/md0`
- `/dev/mapper/sys1AP7-vartmp`
- `/dev/mapper/sys1AP7-tmp`

Edit: My config as I ordered it is suppose to be disk 1 and 2 in RAID1 setup, while disk 3 should be a standalone drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only 3 **physical** devices:

- /dev/sda
- /dev/sdb
- /dev/sdc

[It is simply as by convention, IDE drives will be given device names /dev/hda to /dev/hdd](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/devices.html).

Besides that you have **logical** RAID devices:

- /dev/md0
- /dev/md1
- /dev/md2

[RAID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID) (originally redundant array of inexpensive disks; now commonly redundant array of independent disks) is a data storage virtualization technology that combines multiple disk drive components into a logical unit for the purposes of data redundancy or performance improvement.

RAID needs a Linux kernel framework for mapping block devices onto higher-level virtual block devices, so-called **[device mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper)**:

- /dev/mapper

Comment: Thanks, if I need to mount my 3rd drive to a folder (e.g., /backup), do I mount it to `/dev/sdc` or `/dev/md2`?

Comment: I would try to use RAID: mount /dev/md /backup

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `lsblk` command, it will show the storage devices in a nice tree format. Just beware that it cannot show inside hardware-raid devices etc  that the firmware presents as a single disk.